# test matlab classes defined in different folder

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, class

I've the following matlab project structure:

[image]

`tests` folder contains test classes that must be executed with the testing framework. The class `PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest` is the following one

```
classdef PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

  methods (Test)

    function testDefaultConstructor(this)
      options = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions();
      this.verifyEqual(options.getHostName(), "");
      this.verifyEqual(options.getPort(), "0");
      this.verifyEqual(options.getDatabaseName(), "");
      this.verifyEqual(options.getUsername(), "");
      this.verifyEqual(options.getPassword(), "");
    end
  end
end
```

The script `runAllTests` contains the following code:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite

databaseSuite = TestSuite.fromFolder("tests/WTrade/Database");
result = run(databaseSuite);
```

When I run the script I obtain the following output, with an error:

```
>> runAllTests
Running PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest

================================================================================
Error occurred in PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testDefaultConstructor and it did not run to completion.
    ---------
    Error ID:
    ---------
    'MATLAB:undefinedVarOrClass'
    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    Undefined variable "WTrade" or class "WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions".

    Error in PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testDefaultConstructor (line 6)
          options = WTrade.Database.PostgreSQLConnectionOptions();
================================================================================
.
Done PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest
__________

Failure Summary:

     Name                                                    Failed  Incomplete  Reason(s)
    =======================================================================================
     PostgreSQLConnectionOptionsTest/testDefaultConstructor    X         X       Errored.
```

Basically I cannot use the `PostgreSQLConnectionOptions` inside the test class because it's not found.

How can I fix the code so I can perform unit testing maintaining code and tests folder separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider putting your code into a [project](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/projects.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav). This will allow you to define the appropriate execution environment for your source code, such as ensuring all the right folders are on the path or any other environment management you need to do to ensure your code is working and accessible.

There are other ways to help ensure your source code is available when testing, but if you can use projects (a long time feature of Simulink which are now part of MATLAB as of R2019a) that will likely be the cleanest approach.

Comment: I'm already using a project. The screenshot is taken from a Matlab 2019b project.

Comment: Great, then you should be able to call runtests on the project root folder, which will detect it is a project and load the project to ensure all the paths are added appropriately. Alternatively, you can use TestSuite.fromProject to create the suite, which will do the same thing. Does that help you get going?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is add path to the folder including all sub-directories within it!
This should do the job `addpath(genpath(folder));`, where **folder** is the name of the Parent Directory inside which all your sub-directories are located!